# Do IAP buttons have callbacks?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, revenuecat

I'm using RevenueCat for subscriptions. It works fine when I make the test purchase but I'm having an odd problem. I have a separate "Purchase" button, when pressed, the RevenueCat action sheet appears.

If I press the little x button in the right hand corner to dismiss it or press outside of the actionSheet, inside `Purchases.shared.purchase`, `.purchaseCancelledError` gets called. However if I press the blue Subscription button, and then press the alert's Ok, button, nothing happens. No callbacks get triggered and I have no idea that the user purchased a subscription.

How can I know when the user hits the Subscribe then pressed the OK button from the You're All Set alert?

```
func purchaseButtonTapped() {

    let productID = "..."

    Purchases.shared.getOfferings { [weak self](offerings, error) in
        guard let _ = error else { return }

        for dict in offerings.all {
                
            let offering = dict.value
            let packages = offering.availablePackages
                
            if let indexOfItem = packages.firstIndex(where: { $0.storeProduct.productIdentifier == productID }) {
                    
                let pkg = packages[indexOfItem]
                    
                self?.showSystemActionSheet(for: pkg)
                break
            }
        }
    }
}

func showSystemActionSheet() {

    Purchases.shared.purchase(package: package) { (transaction, customerInfo, error, userCancelled) in

        if let error = error as? RevenueCat.ErrorCode {
            switch error {
            case .purchaseCancelledError: // *** using breakpoints this gets hit when I cancel or dismiss the actionSheet
                return
            case .productAlreadyPurchasedError, .operationAlreadyInProgressForProductError, .receiptInUseByOtherSubscriberError :
                print("purchase is active")
            case .purchaseNotAllowedError:
                print("purchases_not_allowed")
            case .purchaseInvalidError:
                print("invalid_purchase_check_payment_method")
            default: break
            }
            return
        }

        if userCancelled {
            return 
        }

        guard let customerInfo = customerInfo else { 
            return 
        }

        // after the user pressed Subscribe then pressed the OK button from the You're All Set alert, this print statement should get print/get hit with a break point but it never does
        print("the subscribe button and You're All Set alert was tapped")
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no callback provided by Apple to know when the "You're all set" dialog is dismissed. This is controlled at the OS level so even tools like RevenueCat don't have any control over it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do you determine when the user made a purchase?

Comment: RevenueCat give you infoı about user information. You can check such as that. 
 info?.entitlements.all["YOUR_EntitlementID"]?.isActive == true

Comment: @LanceSamaria if you're using RevenueCat you'll know the purchase was completed when the purchase(package: package) call returns. In the callback you probably will check if the Entitlement is active on the CustomerInfo object as Adem pointed out.

Comment: @AdemÖzsayın The code I posted in my question 1) `Purchases.shared.getOfferings` fetches the `entitlementID` which gets the package and 2) `Purchases.shared.purchase` presents the actionSheet that shows the subscribe button. Here's the scenario, the user presses Subscribe on the actionSheet, then presses Ok alert, at either of those points, how do you know to check `info?.entitlements.all["YOUR_EntitlementID"]?.isActive`? At what point do you the developer know to check?

Comment: @enc_life The problem isn't checking the entitlementID, the problem is the callback only gets called if the user cancels or there is an error. A successful subscription doesn't yield a callback as you stated in your answer. I know I can check the entitlementID to find out if the purchase was made, but that's a different issue.

Comment: The callback gets hit for a successful purchase as well. May take 10+ seconds in sandbox because it’s sandbox.